# Google Calendar API not returning all recurring event instances

Tags: google-calendar-api

Some useful information:

1.) I am the creator of this weekly recurring event

2.) All other instances of the event are being returned except for the one on November 2nd

3.) The event in Question is "**IOS Meeting**"

4.) I can fetch the specific event from Google API if I request it specifically by it's ID, but if I request my entire calendar it does not show up

I am using the Google Calendar API via their console over [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list?authuser=5&apix_params=%7B%22calendarId%22%3A%22v7s4ba1tnr3lufl0b7gf3eg40s%40group.calendar.google.com%22%2C%22timeMax%22%3A%222020-11-04T21%3A57%3A09%2B00%3A00%22%2C%22timeMin%22%3A%222020-10-30T21%3A57%3A09%2B00%3A00%22%7D) and in the response it doesn't return this event. If I change the date range to include November 9th ( which is a different IOS Meeting within the same recurring series ) then it returns that event just fine, but the event on November 2nd is not being returned.

I see the google event in my google calendar as evidenced by this screenshot [image: This specific IOS Meeting is showing up when I use google calendar console, but does not show up when I use the API]

Here is what the event looks like when I fetch it from google calendar API specifically by ID. You can see that the creator is **MY** email

```
Google_Service_Calendar_Event {#18698
 +anyoneCanAddSelf: null,
 +attendeesOmitted: null,
 +colorId: null,
 +created: "2020-07-26T05:11:48.000Z",
 +description: """
    \n
   Let's chat about this event \n
   """,
 +endTimeUnspecified: null,
 +etag: ""3208875059494000"",
 +guestsCanInviteOthers: null,
 +guestsCanModify: null,
 +guestsCanSeeOtherGuests: null,
 +hangoutLink: "https://meet.google.com/agu-ndeu-wfw",
 +htmlLink: "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MGhvZjliNGM4ZDNtaDdxaDM3bWdoNms0MnNfMjAyMDExMDJUMjAwMDAwWiB2N3M0YmExdG5yM2x1ZmwwYjdnZjNlZzQwc0Bn",
 +iCalUID: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@google.com",
 +id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20201102T200000Z",
 +kind: "calendar#event",
 +location: null,
 +locked: null,
 +privateCopy: null,
 +recurrence: null,
 +recurringEventId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
 +sequence: 0,
 +status: "confirmed",
 +summary: "iOS Meeting",
 +transparency: null,
 +updated: "2020-11-03T21:05:29.747Z",
 +visibility: null,
 +"creator": Google_Service_Calendar_EventCreator {#6218
   +displayName: null,
   +email: "<my email is here>", <<<<<<<-----------
   +id: null,
   +self: null,
 },
 +"organizer": Google_Service_Calendar_EventOrganizer {#19293
   +displayName: "My Calendar",
   +email: "xxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com",
   +id: null,
   +self: true,
 },
 +"start": Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime {#18649
   +date: null,
   +dateTime: "2020-11-02T20:00:00Z",
   +timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles",
 },
 +"end": Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime {#16575
   +date: null,
   +dateTime: "2020-11-02T21:00:00Z",
   +timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles",
 },
 +"originalStartTime": Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime {#17050
   +date: null,
   +dateTime: "2020-11-02T20:00:00Z",
   +timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles",
 },
```

Could this be a google calendar API bug?

Comment: Can you share your API requests for all three examples you have mentioned?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Here is the API request I am making to fetch my full calendar which doesn't include that IOS Meeting on November 2nd https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list?authuser=5&apix_params=%7B%22calendarId%22%3A%22v7s4ba1tnr3lufl0b7gf3eg40s%40group.calendar.google.com%22%2C%22showDeleted%22%3Atrue%2C%22timeMax%22%3A%222020-11-15T21%3A57%3A09%2B00%3A00%22%2C%22timeMin%22%3A%222020-10-20T21%3A57%3A09%2B00%3A00%22%7D

Comment: @RafaGuillermo and here is the API call to specifically fetch the November 2nd IOS meeting by it's ID https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get?authuser=5&apix_params=%7B%22calendarId%22%3A%22v7s4ba1tnr3lufl0b7gf3eg40s%40group.calendar.google.com%22%2C%22eventId%22%3A%220hof9b4c8d3mh7qh37mgh6k42s_20201102T200000Z%22%7D

Comment: How are the event's recurring settings set up, and what does the full (santised) response from each request look like? (The one for Nov 2 and also the one which covers Nov 3)

Comment: Here are the full responses in this google doc 

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nB5yqe93M4dEXs_8cjSW_laJvLkehzM5aOV6zZF5t7s/edit

Here are the event's recurring settings : 

RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20201123T075959Z;BYDAY=MO

@RafaGuillermo

Answer (score 0):

#### This appears to be a bug!

There is already a report on Google's Issue Tracker which detail the same kind of behaviour:

- [Calendar API listEvent() method results include Recurring Events which have no instances in specified timeframe](https://issuetracker.google.com/36755698)

Google does seem to know about this issue but if it's causing problems you can file your own bug about it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905). I would actually suggest this may be the best course of action to bring the issue to light again.

You can also hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on the aforementioned pages which lets Google know more people are encountering this and so it is more likely to be seen to faster.